# jquery slide effect not works on image defined with percentage height

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I found unusual behavior of images when I apply jquery slideToggle effect on it. With some effort I found that sliding effect will only work if image size is defined in pixels(px), but not if size is in percentage.

**HTML**

```
<a>Click Me</a>

<div class='target'>
    Hello Everyone...<br>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/MHfCk2B.jpg' height='200px' />
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/MHfCk2B.jpg' height='10%' width='30%' />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $('.target').slideToggle();
    });
})
```

Here is jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SrWdW/1/)

*Temporary solution for it is to use fadeToggle function instead.*

Comment: I set up a function for slide, up and down to play with this. Got it to do better on slide up but not slide down. the Fork is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/rQWsE/2/). Still playing with it, to see if I can get the second pic to do correctly, both ways.

Comment: @ROYFinley, Great, It's fun to mash with different codes. It works for slide up, but still no luck for slide down. Maybe it's bug in jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by simply ensuring that all images are defined with pixel heights.  This is actually something you can do dynamically and very simply too:

```
$("img").height(function (_, h) { return h; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrWdW/2/

I should also point out that [`px` and `%` in image `height`/`width` attributes is not valid](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes).